# What is the default user in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

While developing applications in ASP.NET 2 (VS 2005 ) , i remember giving permissions to the default user ASPNET.
Is there any change in ASP.NET4 with regards to the default user ?

Comment: Users are determined by the version of IIS.

Comment: Thanks nuux..But what if Iam using built-in ASP.NET Development Server rather than IIS ?

Comment: In that case you are running under the currently logged in user account. This type of accounts are tricky and most of the time have more permissions than IIS accounts.

Comment: >>.But what if Iam using built-in ASP.NET Development Server rather than IIS ? Why would you care about Cassini? It runs as the logged in user, typically admin. You should be testing with IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what IIS you are on.

Assuming the 7.0/7.5, it is your responsibility to set an identity of the application pool your site with run under.

Take a look at this article:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, what would be the default user If Iam using ASP.NET Development Server rather than IIS

Comment: The development server runs under your own identity (the identity of logged user).

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing has changed in ASP.NET 4.0. What matters is the user account that your application is configured to run under in IIS.

Comment: Thanks Michael..But what if Iam using built-in ASP.NET Development Server rather than IIS ?

Comment: In that case, your application runs as *you*, the account you used to log in to Windows.